# Remove 'paisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitud' on n:m relation using Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a entity `DistribuidorProductoSolicitud` with the following code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="negocio.distribuidor_producto_solicitud", schema="negocio")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\DistribuidorProductoSolicitudRepository")
 */
class DistribuidorProductoSolicitud
{
    ... 

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Pais", inversedBy="distribuidorProductoSolicitudPais", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="nomencladores.pais_distribuidor_producto_solicitud", schema="nomencladores",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="distribuidor_producto_solicitud_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="pais_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $paisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->paisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add paisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais
     *
     * @param AppBundle\Entity\Pais $paises
     */
    public function addPaisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais(Pais $paises)
    {
        $this->paisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais[] = $paises;
    }

    /**
     * Get paisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getPaisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais()
    {
        return $this->paisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais;
    }

   /**
    * Remove paisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais
    *
    * @param \AppBundle\Entity\DistribuidorProductoSolicitud $distribuidorProductoSolicitud
     */
     public function removePaisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais(DistribuidorProductoSolicitud $distribuidorProductoSolicitud)
     {
         $this->paisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais->removeElement($distribuidorProductoSolicitud);
         return $this;
     }

    ...
}
```

How do I delete rows from the relation with `$paisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais`? I have as parameters the `distribuidor_producto_solicitud_id` and `pais_id`.

I'm trying something like this:

```
public function getDistribuidorAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entDistribuidorProductoSolicitud = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:DistribuidorProductoSolicitud')->find($request->query->get('dpsid'));
    $response['success'] = false;
    $status = null;

    if (!$entDistribuidorProductoSolicitud) {
        $response['error'] = $this->get('translator')->trans('mensajes.msgNoEncontrado');
        return new JsonResponse($response, $status ?: 200);
    }

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $entDistribuidorProductoSolicitud->removePaisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais($entDistribuidorProductoSolicitud);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return new JsonResponse($response, $status ?: 200);
}
```

But I'm unsure it will works, any help or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generated the class using the command `doctrine:generate:entities`, you must have a method called `removePaisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais(Pais $paises)` or something of the kind. If not, just create it.

```
public function removePaisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais(Pais $paises)
{
  $this->paisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais->removeElement($paises);
}
```

With `distribuidor_producto_solicitud_id` find the object of `DistribuidorProductoSolicitud` type you want to remove a `Pais` entity. For instance, from a controller:

```
$distPais = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select("s")
                ->from('MyBundle:DistribuidorProductoSolicitud', 's')
                ->innerJoin('s.paisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais', 'f')
                ->where('s.id=:id')
                ->setParameter('id', $distribuidor_producto_solicitud_id)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getSingleResult();
```

Find the entity within the ArrayCollection that corresponds to `pais_id`. You can create a method in your entity to search the array or do it directly in the controller. It's up to you.

```
$pais_ent = NULL;
foreach($distPais->getPaisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais() as $pais) {
 if($pais->getId() == $pais_id) {
  $pais_ent = $pais;
  break;
 }
}
```

if $pais_ent is NULL you can throw an exception. I'm going to assume that that case doesn't happen.

```
$distPais->removePaisesDistribuidorProductoSolicitudPais($pais_ent);
$em->flush();
```

It should have removed the association from the joining table.

Hope it helps.

[Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#removing-associations)